# R Studio: How to replace the blank value with the corresponding row value of the second column

Tags: r, rstudio, rows, blank-line

[R]
Hi, for every row in my data i would to have the **blanks** in column REAL_TIME_ARR being replaced by the corresponding row value from column REAL_TIME_DEP. I cannot seem to get it to work for the hundreds of rows I have.

```
> TwentyFourSeptTrainData
REAL_TIME_ARR  REAL_TIME_DEP
               08:38
08:40          08:41
08:45          08:46
09:00          09:02
               09:07
09:10          09:11
and so on and so on
```

So my goal is for my data to look like this:

```
  > TwentyFourSeptTrainData
REAL_TIME_ARR  REAL_TIME_DEP
08:38          08:38
08:40          08:41
08:45          08:46
09:00          09:02
09:07          09:07
09:10          09:11
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the blanks coded as "" or as NA?

Comment: Try this: df$A1 <- ifelse(df$A1 == "", df$A3, df$A1)

Comment: The blanks are coded as ""

Comment: It hasn't given me the data i wanted. Hang on, let me edit my question a little bit more specific

Comment: If i use your line, i don't get the corresponding value

Comment: See the updated answer. Is it still not working?

Comment: Im getting weird nmbrs, the blank values are now filled up with 67745 and 68501 and even the normal values are overwritten with random numbers. Any idea how?

Comment: Likely a formatting issue. Please provide your data with dput(TwentyFourSeptTrainData) instead to make it easier to reproduce

Comment: Nice! I can see it worked in my console, but when I open the table it hasn't been done. Any idea how? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TwentyFourSeptTrainData$REAL_TIME_ARR <- ifelse(TwentyFourSeptTrainData$REAL_TIME_ARR == "",
                                                TwentyFourSeptTrainData$REAL_TIME_DEP,
                                                TwentyFourSeptTrainData$REAL_TIME_ARR)
```

Result:

```
TwentyFourSeptTrainData
REAL_TIME_ARR REAL_TIME_DEP
1         08:38         08:38
2         08:40         08:41
3         08:45         08:46
4         09:00         09:02
5         09:07         09:07
6         09:10         09:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
TwentyFourSeptTrainData <- TwentyFourSeptTrainData %>%
  mutate(REAL_TIME_ARR = case_when(REAL_TIME_ARR == "" ~ REAL_TIME_DEP,
                                   TRUE ~ REAL_TIME_ARR))
```

Result:

```
TwentyFourSeptTrainData
  REAL_TIME_ARR REAL_TIME_DEP
1         08:38         08:38
2         08:40         08:41
3         08:45         08:46
4         09:00         09:02
5         09:07         09:07
6         09:10         09:11
```

Comment: Nice! I can see it worked in my console, but when I open the table it hasn't been done. Any idea how?

Comment: Save it back to the data frame, and you'll see the result. I.e. TwentyFourSeptTrainData <- TwentyFourSeptTrainData %>% ...